# Wordpress - Add a user as custom field of CPT

Tags: wordpress

Intro info:

I have a Custom Post Type (CPT) called Service.
I am already connecting users to this CPT using the plug-in 'Posts 2 Posts', this is a many to many relation, and these users connected to the CPT represent the 'team' of said Service.

Alright so here's the headscratcher:
Now I want to create a custom field in the CPT Service, which will be the Director of the Service. Say a field called 'Director' in which the value is a User. 
Ideally, the value of the field Director is a User, not a string representing the user name or anything like that.

I have no idea how to start tackling this issue and some brightness on the subject would be strongly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

save it as post_meta. e.g if you have the user email:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email');
update_post_meta($serviceid, '_director', $user->ID);
```

If you are setting this up in the admin section you can add a meta box and attach a action to save_posts to save a html field where you select a user. Google add_meta_box, there are a load of tutorials on this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer David, it definetly helped me get to learn Wordpress a bit more!
However, I ended up creating a third CPT called 'Role' in which I connect users to Role and Role to Service using the plug-in mentioned above. Not only it solved my problem, but also made it easier should the project need new roles for the future other than 'Director'.